# How do i use UNICODE in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

```
SELECT column!
FROM table!
WHERE column1='राहुल';
```

This return 0 rows.

column1 is nvarchar2(100)

I also tried

```
WHERE column1 = N'राहुल';
```

still it returns nothing

Comment: What specific DBMS are you using? What is the collation of your table?

Comment: I am using oracle 10g. The table is created using following syntax

Comment: create table table1 (column1 nvarchar2(100))

Comment: You can use [the dump function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/DUMP.html) to examine the data that's actually in the column, to make sure it has the codepoints you expect, doesn't have trailing whitespace, etc.

Comment: What do you get from `select 'राहुल' from dual;`?

Comment: What is the `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` of your database? I think Unicode was not that common in 10g (which means 17 years ago)

Comment: If you are running the SQL statement from a terminal or shell, chances are the terminal/shell is the problem. Try it with SQL Developer or a similar GUI tool instead.